# Adding folder to iPad bundle works on simulator, not on device

Tags: ios, ipad, directory, bundle, target

I have two targets for my app.
Each has its file own Info.plist and a custom folder included (as references, not as group).
When I run my target on the simulator the folder is correctly inserted in the bundle and the files inside it are read without problems.
This is the code to read the folder path:

```
NSBundle* mainBundle;
NSString *fileFolder;
mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSLog(@"Bundle path: %@", [mainBundle bundlePath]);
NSLog(@"Folder name: %@", [mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CustomFolder"]);
NSString *folder = [mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CustomFolder"];
fileFolder = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:folder ofType:nil] retain];
NSLog(@"Folder: %@", fileFolder);
```

If I try to debug the app on the device, Bundle path and Folder name are correct, but the folder string is null.
I've checked inside my app product, and the there is the right folder, with all the files.
So what's the problem? Is it a read permission issue?

**UPDATE**
The resulting path running in iPad Simulator is this

/***/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/8337B9E5-1BFE-4A17-969E-E3E6E43193D6/MyApp.app/CustomFolder/

**UPDATE 2**
The problem is that I've added the folder with "Create folder references for any added folders".
I replaced pathForResource with stringByAppendingPathComponent, but the problem now persist for subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath.

Comment: Is it a case sensitivity issue? On the Mac (including the iOS simulator), the file system is not case sensitive, but it is on the device.

Comment: the folder has the same case in both name and code references.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you use the correct place in the iPad memory. there is no restrictions to where you save stuff on the simulator. This code works

```
+(NSString*) pathToDocumentsFolder
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
return documentsDirectory;  
}
+(NSString*) pathToFileInDocumentsFolder:(NSString*)filename
{
NSString *pathToDoc = [NSBundle pathToDocumentsFolder];
return [pathToDoc stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
}
```

Comment: my folder is not in the document folder, is in the bundle. see my post update to the complete path.

Comment: what version of iOS do you have on your iPhone?